# UITextField Keyboard international?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, ascii

I created a uitextfield in xcode4 for my iPad app. It sends the strings to and from devices via bluetooth connection.

```
    textfield=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 700, 45)];  
    textfield.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    textfield.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textfield.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    textfield.delegate=self;
    textfield.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0];
    textfield.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;  
    textfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
    textfield.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault;
   textfield.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySend;
    textfield.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"el", nil]
                                              forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

I want to be able to enable international languages. I Changed the iPad settings so that the keyboard has english, french, Spanish, russian, and chinese. However, in the app, it can only switch between French and English and Spanish.

I changed

```
 textfield.keyboardType= UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable;
```

but that didn't work either.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can make Russian and Chinese work?

Comment: Is this a secure field?

Comment: Side note - you state you are using Xcode 4. Apple now only accepts apps using Xcode 5 and fully supports iOS 7. You should upgrade.

Comment: Try setting the keyboard type to `UIKeyboardTypeDefault`. ASCII only has the letters A-Z, not letters from Russian or Chinese.

Comment: Hi @mikael, hm I'm not sure what that means. It's sending messages via bluetooth

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, going to upgrade very soon! And thnk you so much, not sure why I didn't think of using UIKeyboardTypeDefault. It fixed everything!

Comment: If you check secure in storyboard (i.e. for a password) then you can't show russian or chinese keyboards. That said @rmaddy is giving you the correct answer I had missed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set the keyboard type to `Alphabet` which can't show all languages.

Change the keyboard type to `UIKeyboardTypeDefault` to allow any keyboard to be chosen.